# question about how to flicker led in ipad iphone using connector

Tags: iphone, ipad

Experts, I want to develop an app (with accompanying hardware) that turns 2 leds (Light Emitting Diodes), in different frequencies, I found this pin out for the iphone/ipad connector
[link](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Apple_iPod,_iPad_and_iPhone_dock).
The questions are:

1. what pin should be the best to accomplish my flickering led? pin#? and and (GND off course),
2. what function in objective C will allow me to do this?,
3. I found this [site](http://www.chargeconverter.com/shop/connector.htm) for buying the connectors, do you have a better one?

I intend to have the earphones connected as well, so the sound pins are not an option,

thank you in advance!

edit>
here an example of an 
external flash light for the iphone
[light](http://www.freakgeeks.com/2010/790/external-flash-light-for-your-iphone3g3gs4ipod-4g-ipad/)

so I ask you guys please the same question, what pin and what function is used to turn this light on?, I can take care of the frequencie generation and the electronics, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExternalAccessory.framework is the best place to start. It's covered in the [External Accessory Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> Manufacturers must build explicit
>   support into their accessory hardware
>   for communicating with iOS. As part of
>   this support, an accessory must
>   support at least one command protocol,
>   which is a custom scheme for sending
>   data back and forth between the
>   accessory and an attached application.
>   Apple does not maintain a registry of
>   protocols; it is up to the
>   manufacturer to decide which protocols
>   to support and whether to use custom
>   protocols or standard protocols
>   supported by other manufacturers.

It's basically all up to you to create the protocol but the ExternalAccessory.framework is where iOS meets the external device.

*Original answer, which would sound snarky to an electronics engineer, removed. :-)*

Comment: hi, thank for your answer, actually I'm an electronics engineer ;P but I also program, I have experience with PIC and arduino,  my question is about the software side of the interaction, I have seen projects that read an analog signal using the sound input... so flickering a led would just take advantage of the serial capabilities of the connector; my question is then to someone that knows what pin can be used and the actual function that can be used to flicker a signal (I can take care of using the right voltage etc) thanks

Comment: please check the edit, I've included an example of a external light, wich is a high bright led, the difference is that I would want it flickering cheers